# How to get total download size of a list?

Tags: command-line, files, wget

Imagine that, I have got `download-list.txt`. It contains some file urls:

```
http://example.com/a.txt
http://example.com/b.txt
http://example.com/c.txt
http://example.com/d.txt
http://example.com/e.txt
```

When I run `wget -i download-list.txt --spider`, it shows like:

```
http://example.com/a.txt
...
Length: 128 (128B) [text/txt]
...
http://example.com/b.txt
...
Length: 120 (120B) [text/txt]
...
http://example.com/c.txt
...
Length: 100 (100B) [text/txt]
...
http://example.com/d.txt
...
Length: 90 (90B) [text/txt]
...
http://example.com/e.txt
...
Length: 80 (80B) [text/txt]
...
```

But, I do not need individual file size, I need total file size:

```
518 (128+120+100+90+80)
```

How to achieve this result? (Any other methods without `wget` is also appreciated)

Comment: Without querying the site to determine the length of the file, it's impossible.  And it only works if the remote server sends us the expected size of the file, so short of downloading the file and getting the total filesize/length there's no foolproof way to determine the actual filesize of the downloadable files in the list of files.

Comment: @ThomasWard, thanks for the reply. However, what I need was only printing the total size, not individual size. By the way, the accepted answer satisfies all of my requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use `curl`:

```
<download-list.txt xargs -n1 curl -sI |
  awk '/[cC]ontent-[lL]ength/{total_size+=$2} END{ print total_size " bytes" }'
```

The `curl` will print the header information ([which file?](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso)) as like below that contains `"Content-Length"` in bytes (if the remote server can provide that); then with `awk` we are summing-up the second column which is the file size for the line if matched with `Content-Length` and at the END print the total size saved in `total_size` variable.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 1921843200
Content-Type: application/x-iso9660-image
ETag: "728d0000-56ac4c63786e2"
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 18:44:15 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 23 May 2018 16:45:08 GMT
```

from [**`man curl`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/curl.1.html)

> **-I, --head**
>                 (HTTP/FTP/FILE)  Fetch  the  HTTP-header  only!  HTTP-servers feature the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing
>   but the
>                 header of a document. When used on an FTP or FILE file, curl displays the file size and last modification time only.
>
> **-s, --silent**
>             Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the  data  you  ask
>             for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.

Comment: of course and I have added that in my answer.

Comment: You can replace ``\`` with `|` and remove the `|` on the next line.

Comment: I edited while I don't like pipelines and more if that was at the end alone  :    )